# PHP: How to check for timeout exception in Guzzle 4?

Tags: php, exception, timeout, guzzle

Guzzle throws an exception if an error occured during the request. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be an error specific to timeouts - which is important for me as I know that those can ocassionally occur. I'd like to retry the corresponding request and need to able to tell if the error occured due to a timeout.

From the [docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/clients.html#decode-content):

```
// Timeout if a server does not return a response in 3.14 seconds.
$client->get('/delay/5', ['timeout' => 3.14]);
// PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException'
```

The `RequestException` has the info in its`message` property:

```
"cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 3114 milliseconds with 0 bytes received"
```

So I could evaluate the message pattern but this feels kinda wrong, because those messages could easily be changed in the future.

**Is there a better/more stable way to check for timeouts when using guzzle 4?**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I've fixed it with stopping an event’s propagation. You can read more about this [here](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html#event-propagation).

```
use GuzzleHttp\Event\ErrorEvent;
use GuzzleHttp\Message\Response;

$client->getEmitter()->on('error', function(ErrorEvent $event) {
    $event->stopPropagation();
    $event->intercept(new Response(200));
    echo $event->getException()->getMessage();
});
```

In your case this will output `cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 3114 milliseconds with 0 bytes received` without throwing an `RequestException`.

Comment: I needed to remove the line `$event->intercept(new Response(200));` so not to get `Call to a member function getMessage() on null`. Worked after that. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The Exeption is generated here:

https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Adapter/Curl/CurlAdapter.php

```
private function handleError(
    TransactionInterface $transaction,
    $info,
    $handle
) {
    $error = curl_error($handle);
    $this->releaseEasyHandle($handle);
    RequestEvents::emitError(
        $transaction,
        new AdapterException("cURL error {$info['curl_result']}: {$error}"),
        $info
    );
}
```

while this is a private function, you have two options:

- clone the entire file, give it a new name, use this instead of the CurlAdapter and throw another Exception than "AdapterException"
- edit the file and throw another Exeption than "AdapterException" but in this case, your Guzzle is no longer maintainable.