# Breaking out of a Gearman loop

Tags: php, gearman

I have a php application that gets requests for part numbers from our server. At that moment, we reach out to a third party API to gather pricing information to make sure we have the latest pricing for that particular request. Sometimes the third party API is slow or it might be down, so we have a database that stores the latest pricing requests for each particular part number that we can use as a fallback. I'd like to run the request to the third party API and the database in parallel using Gearman. Here is the idea:

1. Receive request
2. Through gearman, create two jobs:

   - Request to third party API
   - MySQL database lookup
3. Wait in a loop and return the results based on the following conditions:

   - If the third party API has completed return that result, return that result immediately
   - If an elapsed time has passed, (e.g. 2 seconds) and the third party API hasn't responded, return the MySQL lookup data

Using gearman, my thoughts were to either run the two tasks in the foreground and break out of runTasks() within the setCompleteCallback() call, or to run them in the background and check in on the two tasks within a separate loop and check in on the tasks using jobStatus().

Unfortunately, I can't get either route to work for me while still getting access to the resulting data. Is there a a better way, or are there some existing examples of how someone has made this work?

Comment: I would think that the only gearman task you would need is the API lookup one, the MySQL lookup you can do from the client app, right?

Comment: The only reason I'm doing the SQL lookup is as a backup in case the 3rd party API is late/broken. It doesn't have to be a separate task, but my thought is that I can at least have the results available right away in case I run out of time. At any rate, I still don't have a way to run the 3rd party lookup in the background and wait for up to my limit before moving on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've described a single blocking problem, namely the results of an 3rd-party API lookup.  There's two ways you can handle this from my point of view, either you could abort the attempt altogether if you decide that you've run out of time or you could report back to the client that you ran out of time but continue on with the lookup anyway, just to update your local cache just in case it happens to respond slower than you would like.  I'll describe how I would go about the former problem because that would be easier.

From the client side:

```
$request = array(
    'productId' => 5,
);
$client = new GearmanClient( );
$client->addServer( '127.0.0.1', 4730 );
$results = json_decode($client->doNormal('apiPriceLookup', json_encode( $request )));

if($results && property_exists($results->success) && $results->success) {
    // Use local data
} else {
    // Use fresh data
}
```

This will create a job on the job server with a function name of `'apiPriceLookup'` and pass it the workload data containing a product id of `5`.  It will wait for the results to come back, and check for a `success` property. If it exists and is true, then the api lookup was successful.

The idea is to set the timeout condition then in the worker task, which completely depends on how you're implementing the API lookup.  If you're using cURL (or some wrapper around cURL), you can see the answer to how to detect a timeout [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867891/php-curl-timeout-error-detection).

From the worker side:

```
$worker= new GearmanWorker(); 
$worker->addServer(); 
$worker->addFunction("apiPriceLookup", "apiPriceLookup", $count);

while ($worker->work());

function apiPriceLookup($job) {
    $payload = json_decode($job->workload());

    try {
        $results = [
            'data' => PerformApiLookupForProductId($payload->productId),
            'success' => true,
        ];
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $results = ['success' => false];
    }

    return json_encode($results);
}
```

This just creates a `GearmanWorker` object and subscribes it the function of `apiPriceLookup`.  It will call the function `apiPriceLookup` whenever a client submits a task to the job server. That function calls out to another function, `PerformApiLookupForProductId`, which should be written so as to throw an exception whenever a timeout condition occurs.

I don't think this would be considered using exceptions to control logic flow, I think timeout conditions generally are exceptional (or should be) events. For instance, Guzzle will throw a `GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException` [when it has decided to timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661591/php-how-to-check-for-timeout-exception-in-guzzle-4).

Comment: I agree this would be a good way to go, but unfortunately I can't just throw an exception since I want the process to continue and write the data to the database so it's there for the next time I make a request.

Comment: There's a few options you got for that, a couple that come to mind are setting up a cron to just call your task to refresh from your API all products every hour (or day, or twice a day) and then only relying on your local cache and be ok with the fact that you have day-old data. Or, you can run a background process that indicates a status 1/2 (numerator / denominator) when timeout condition occurs and 2/2 when results were fetched successfully, and then block on the web server while you're waiting for the status to be updated

Comment: Going to accept this as the best answer. However, in the end, I decided to run this in the background, and have the background task throw the answer into a Redis store, so my main app could check back there to see if there was any data. It seems to work ok.